# using processing instructions to provide meta informations?

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxb

I intend to add some version information to my XML data.
Since my tool evolves over the years so does my XML content/format.

I might add some attribute to the root element, but I don't like this solution very much, as the version information is not an intrinsic property of my business class.
An other idea is to introduce a versioned namespace for each new version....

I observed that MS used some `<?mso-application ... ?>` PI to tag their documents.
Is it a good idea to so and to introduce my own custom PI to carry my meta information?
Is there a list of commonly used PI tags or how to design my own PI?

To enable my tool to read former/outdated XML data I thing of plugging some XSLT transformation in front of my unmashaller to adapt former versions automatically.

Thus my business class does not have to care about any outdated XML syntax.

Any suggestions?

Dieter.

Answer (score 1):

Using a versioned namespace is definitely a bad idea. It means that if you make a 3% change to your schema, which affects only 1% of users, every user is going to have to change their applications to change to the new namespace, or even worse, handle the complexity of recognizing multiple namespaces.

Using a PI is not a common solution, but there's no obvious harm in it; except perhaps the fact that you can't enforce the presence or content of the PI during schema validation.

In my view the cleanest solution is a version attribute on the root element. That's the way XSLT does it and it has worked well.